# Unable to get 0.00% for cells with 0 observations

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataset which looks like:

```
ID   week  status
20    0       2
20    1       2
20    2       2
20    3       2
20    4       3
```

I need the proportion of status by week.
So I used the code

```
g_young= dat_young%>%group_by(week)%>%count(status)%>%mutate(dist=prop.table(n)*100)
```

I get the answer all right, but, the issue is that cells where the observation is 0, R is not showing the percentage  for those as 0.00.
For example:

```
week    status   n      dist
0        1      1957     12.9
0        3      1301     86.4
0        5      90       0.59
```

In normal situation this would not have been an issue, but, I need to make a graph after this and the fact that there is no value for status 2 and4 in the above table is causing a weird step like function in the graph. Any ideas, how I could sort this out?

Thanks a lot. Appreciate the time and effort in helping me with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to convert your status variable into a factor type and then add the argument `.drop = FALSE` to the `count()` function.

For example:

```
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))

dat <- tibble(week = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2),
              status = c(1,1,2,1,1,2,3,1,2,1))

dat

#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>     week status
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1     0      1
#>  2     0      1
#>  3     0      2
#>  4     0      1
#>  5     0      1
#>  6     1      2
#>  7     1      3
#>  8     1      1
#>  9     1      2
#> 10     2      1

dat %>%
  mutate(status = factor(status)) %>%
  group_by(week) %>%
  count(status, .drop = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(dist = prop.table(n)*100)

#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#> # Groups:   week [3]
#>    week status     n  dist
#>   <dbl> <fct>  <int> <dbl>
#> 1     0 1          4    80
#> 2     0 2          1    20
#> 3     0 3          0     0
#> 4     1 1          1    25
#> 5     1 2          2    50
#> 6     1 3          1    25
#> 7     2 1          1   100
#> 8     2 2          0     0
#> 9     2 3          0     0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

[r](/questions/tagged/r)[dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr)

Comment: Works like a dream. Thanks a lot.